# Redirect Controller to Another Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Say for example, I have **ControllerA** which has about **10 Actions** in it, when a user types into the URL **/ControllerA/{Any Action name}** it should redirect to **/ControllerB/Index**

Is there a simple way to redirect all actions in a **ControllerA** to **ControllerB** without having to write **RedirectToAction** in all the actions in **ControllerA**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear -

I can see potentially three different scenarios (maybe more?)
1. Do you actually need to redirect from all these actions before doing anything (so why are they even there?), 
2. Do you want them to execute and then go to ControllerB. 
3. Do you just want to invoke ControllerB directly for all these 10 Urls?

For scenario one you can just use attribute routing on controllerA (or even on controllerB) and have a single method that redirects to index.
For scenario two you want to override OnActionExecuted
For scenario three you want to put attribute routes directly on Index with all the paths that lead there.

Edit:

you can do something in routing that will short circuit controller A.

```
if (configurationCondition)
{
    routes.MapRoute("Hijaack",
        url: "controllerA/{*theRest}",
        defaults: new { controller = "controllerB", action = "Index" });
}
```

This is more loose than requiring the actions to match exactly to what is on controllerA. It avoids the redirect completely, which should be a nicer experience to the end user.

It can be tightened up to more specific routes with attribute routing.

Comment: To your points, here's what my scenario is 
1) Yes, based on a certain conditions set in the configuration file, i need to redirect any request that comes towards **ControllerA** redirected to **ControllerB**
2) No, i do not need to execute them.
3) Yes
I believe Igor's answer points me to what I've asked for. Why Down Vote it?

Comment: Because it seems very inefficient an adds an extra hop. I would in this case do something completely different. And either provide an extra routes that hijacks the actions from controllerA and maps them to controllerB. Adding this to the example in the answer

Comment: And I see your point about downvoting, unfortunately it is too late to upvote again, unless the answer is editted ;)

Comment: Thanks for tip.. this is definitely a better way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other way of doing this without affecting the ControllerA which would be more suitable:

- by using a filter in which when you see that the user is asking for this controller you return a redirect response to the 2nd controller
- by using a routing rule

Both can be implemented by taking care of your web config settings.